# Adding rows to another variable. The rows are already available in another csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, syntax, jupyter-notebook

There are 1919 rows and 12 columns in my file. There is a column named Genres that tells about the Genres of the games. 
SAMPLE DATA:

**Genres**

```
Games, Strategy, Puzzle 

Games, Entertainment, Action 

...

... 

Games, Strategy, Puzzle.
```

In such a way there are 1919 rows. I want to select rows that have the puzzle in them and store those entire rows in a separate variable without harming the original document. Just like copy and paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have `string` type `Genres` column then answer would be

Using [`contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to get boolean index where word match and in the end reset index for new dataframe.

```py
df2 = df[df.Genres.str.contains('Puzzle')].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`df2 = df[df['Genres'] == 'Puzzle'].copy()`
This will copy all rows with `Genres == Puzzle` into new dataframe `df2`

Comment: This one didn't print any of the rows. It showed blank. Although the code line is running. Thanks for the help though.